# sequelize how disable output sql with bindparam when logging

Tags: logging, sequelize.js, bindparam

*1. when in development,i want sequelize outout sql so that i can debug some problem(by logging:true).*

*2. but sequelize output sql with bindparameter,so i can not execute it.*

*this is what i want:*

```
  INSERT INTO `login_attempts` VALUES (1,'bob@example.com',1,'2016-11-30 18:20:26.540 +00:00');
```

*but i get:*

```
INSERT INTO `login_attempts` VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4);
```

*3. how can i disable output sql with bind parameter when development?*

Comment: Related Sequelize.js issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10067

Answer (score 0):

```
const config = {
    "dbConfig": {
        "dialect": process.env.DbDialect,

        "logging": true,
        "logQueryParameters": true,  //

...
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it